# Export all the coordinates of all the elements in svg d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have several elements in SVG d3 and there are several transformations applied to those. I would want to export all the coordinates of all elements in JSON format or any other format.

The output format is required to be processed by some other application.

Note: I don't have data field in any SVG D3 elements and I don't want to output in svg/html format using serializaToString. I tried with JSON.stringify("lines.data") but I get null since I have not defined.

//This is how I add line.

```
 line = d3.select(container).append("line")

          .attr("x1", x1)
          .attr("y1", y1)
          .attr("x2", x2)
          .attr("y2", y2)
          .attr("name", name)
          .attr("class",className)
          .call(drag)
          .on("mousedown", mousedown2);
```

//This function doesn't work since I don't have data in my line.

```
function generateit(){

var data = '';

var circles = vis.selectAll("circle");
var test = circles.data;
var json_circles = JSON.stringify(circles.data());
data += 'var jsonCircles = '+json_circles+';<br><br>';

var lines = vis.selectAll(".line");
var json_lines = JSON.stringify(lines.data());
data += 'var jsonLines = '+json_lines+';';

d3.select("#console").html(data);

 }
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried, so we can help you?

Comment: I just edited to post some of the snippet of my code. @zfor.